# 二項分布に従う乱数を得る際のOverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, windows, numpy

ある二項分布（試行回数 = 1.5*10^11, 成功確率 = 10^(-8))に従う乱数を10個得たいと思っています。
二項分布の期待値や標準偏差から考えると1500±75くらいの乱数が得られるはずなのですが、OverflowErrorが出てしまいます。
コードの不備や、エラーの回避方法などございましたら、ご教授お願い致します。以下のコードは念の為 `sys.maxsize` の値の確認も含んでいます。

```
import numpy as np
import sys

print(sys.maxsize)

arr = np.random.binomial(1.5*(10**11), 1e-08, 10)
print(arr)
```

エラーの内容としては、以下の通りです。

```
line 6, in <module>
    arr = np.random.binomial(1.5*(10**11), 1e-08, 10)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 3360, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.binomial
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
9223372036854775807
```

Comment: 参考:[Alternative to numpy.random.binomial that allows 64 bits or more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766009/)

Comment: どうも試行回数パラメータは`int32`の範囲内に収める必要があるようですね。そのため試行回数を`1.5*(10**9)`まで下げれば動作はするようなのと、合わせて個々の数値を1500近辺にするならば`1e-06`にすると出来るようです。

Comment: @metropolis さん、引用先を参照して解決しました。恥ずかしながら正規分布に近似することは考えていなかったです。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @kunif さん、コメントありがとうございました。その方法でもそんなに変わらない値は得られそうです。